# SQL to locate missing records in one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL and I need to ensure all my items are located in exactly 5 specific locations like below. My SQL is not good enough to get the correct syntax. The issue I face is that my items are located in only few of the 5 locations and I need to find the missing ones which i will use to upload manually into the database.

This is what I am hoping to achieve for all my items in exactly these locations.

[image]

Issue is that the database table has many locations but I need to find only those records where the item is missing in any of the 5 specific locations, the 5 specific locations being Austin, Boston, Chicago, Dallas and Houston.
In the below screenshot, the ones in red are what im trying to obtain via an SQL.

[image]

Below is what I want the SQL to output. As mentioned above, once I find the missing records, I will manually upload them into the database. Any help with the SQL will be gladly helpful. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
WITH locations (location) AS (
  SELECT 'Austin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Boston' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chicago' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dallas' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Houston' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t.code,
       l.location
FROM   locations l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table t
       PARTITION BY (t.code)
       ON (l.location = t.locations)
WHERE  t.locations IS NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (code, locations) AS
SELECT 'item1', 'Austin'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Boston'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Denver'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Logan'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Houston'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Seattle'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Nashville'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item1', 'Los Angeles' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Austin'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Sioux Falls' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Omaha'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Dallas'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Houston'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Seattle'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Nashville'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item2', 'Los Angeles' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Austin'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Boston'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Chicago'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Dallas'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Atlanta'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Seattle'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'item3', 'Nashville'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CODE | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | Chicago |
| item1 | Dallas |
| item2 | Boston |
| item2 | Chicago |
| item3 | Houston |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o_jLrGov)

Comment: Hi MTO, I know that Im doing something wrong here but just to give you an idea, the table has hundreds of locs and thousands of items and what Im trying to achieve is more like an exception check. So that being said, my table is called sku and item and loc are called item and loc respectively. Here is what I replicated but its not giving an output.  As I mentioned before my SQl syntax is not good at the moment.

Comment: My replication --> WITH loc AS (
  SELECT 'Austin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Boston' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Chicago' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dallas' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Houston' FROM DUAL
)SELECT t.item,
       l.loc
FROM   loc l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sku t
       PARTITION BY (t.item)
       ON (l.loc = t.loc)
WHERE  t.loc IS NULL and t.item = 'egitem;

Comment: and i used one item as a test.

Comment: @redoctober You need to give the column in the sub-query factoring clause an alias. Either `WITH loc (loc) AS (` or `WITH loc AS ( SELECT 'Austin' AS loc FROM DUAL ...` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vube42Y_)

Comment: WITH locations (loc) AS (SELECT ..... FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.item,
       l.loc
FROM   locations l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sku t
       PARTITION BY (t.item)
       ON (l.locations = t.loc)
WHERE  t.loc is NULL

Comment: I ran the above and error I get is l.locations invalid identifier

Comment: @redoctober `WITH table_name (column_name) AS ( ... ) SELECT .... FROM table_name table_alias LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON (table_alias.column_name = ...)` don't mix up the table name, table alias and column name. So for your query, `ON (l.locations =` should be `ON (l.loc =`

Comment: WITH SKU (l.Loc) AS (SELECT …. FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.Item,        l.Loc
FROM   Sku l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Sku t
       PARTITION BY (t.Item)
       ON (l.Loc = t.Loc)
WHERE  t.Sku is NULL;

but I get the error 'missing keyword'

Comment: @redoctober I really can't tell what is wrong with your query because you've redacted parts with `...`. If you want help then provide a fiddle (like the one linked in the question) that replicates the error (or ask a new question and include a [MRE] with the complete query).

Comment: WITH SKU (Loc) AS (SELECT 'loc1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'loc2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'loc3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'loc4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'loc5' FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.Item, l.Loc
FROM   Sku l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Sku t
       PARTITION BY (t.Item)
       ON (l.Loc = t.Loc)
WHERE  t.Sku is NULL;

Comment: @redoctober I don't see a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Hang on..trying to add one...my first time.

Comment: I think Ill add a new question with the query and a reproducible example.

Comment: added a new question in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Using simplified data since you've only provided images.

If apple and kiwi are what we want to check for as missing.

Rationale - Cross join to create all pairs of id and value we want to see. Minus to remove the ones we actually see. The result is what is missing. As long as you aren't dealing with large volumes the cross join isn't too painful.

fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/zexvXlAg

| ID | FRUIT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 1 | orange |
| 1 | kiwi |
| 2 | pear |
| 3 | apple |

```
create table some_test_data
  (
    id int,
    fruit varchar(255)
  );

insert into some_test_data values 
  (1,'apple'),
  (1,'orange'),
  (1,'kiwi'),
  (2,'pear'),
  (3,'apple');

with required_domain as 
  (
   select all_ids.id,
          x.fruit
     from (values ('apple') , ('kiwi'))  as X(fruit)
    cross
     join (select distinct
                  id
             from some_test_data 
          ) all_ids
  )
select id,
       fruit
  from required_domain
 minus
select id,
       fruit
  from some_test_data;
```

| ID | FRUIT |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | apple |
| 2 | kiwi |
| 3 | kiwi |

Comment: Thanks both. Testing it today. Will report back soon.

Comment: @redoctober MT0's is pretty much guaranteed to outperform this. Wasn't aware of that partitioned join feature in Oracle. It's a very clean way to do it.